# Copy lines into new file named after the multiple input files

Tags: python, filenames

I want to use this script to get all lines that start with #Solution out of multiple files in the directory and put them together in a new file that is named after the sample id that is in the title of the input files.
The directory has multiple files of different samples (so different sample id's) so I want to make it for all the different samples if that makes sense.

The names of the input files are like 234567_Genename.aldy and I want the new file to be called 234567.txt .

My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

dr = "/home/nwalraven/Result_pgx/Runfolder/Runres_Aldy"
outfile = "/home/nwalraven/Result_pgx/Runfolder/Aldy_res_txt/.txt" 
tag = ".aldy"


for f in os.listdir(dr):
    if f.endswith(tag):
        print(f)
        for line in open(dr+"/"+f).readlines(): 
            if line.startswith("#Solution"): 
                open(outfile, "+a").write(f.split('.')[0] + "\n")
                open(outfile, "+a").write(line + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `with` context manager whenever you use `open()` so that the file is properly closed at the end.

```py
for f in os.listdir(dr):
    new_lines = [] # clear out this list for each new file we look at
    if f.endswith(tag):
        print(f)
        new_file_name = f.split('_')[0]+'.txt' # get the name of the file before the '_' and add '.txt' to it
        with open(dr+"/"+f) as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                if line.startswith("#Solution"):
                  new_lines.append(line) # make a list of all of the lines for the new file  
        with open(dr+"/"+new_file_name,"w",newline='\n') as new_file:
            new_file.writelines(new_lines) # write all those new lines to the new file at once
```

I'm not sure if I captured exactly what you are trying to do - I didn't use the `outfile` at all, but it didn't make sense what it was for compared to what you wrote in the summary info.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! It is very close to what I am looking for. I changed a few things but do tell me if the changes I made make sense. with open(dr+"/"+new_file_name,"w",newline='\n') as new_file: was changed to with open(outdr+"/"+new_file_name,"w",newline='\n') as new_file: and added a definition for the out directory.

Comment: I also changed new_lines.append(line) 
        with open(dr+"/"+new_file_name,"w",newline='\n') as new_file:
            new_file.writelines(new_lines) to -> with open(outdr+"/"+new_file_name,"w",newline='\n') as new_file:
                   new_file.write(f.split('.')[0] + "\n")
                   new_file.write(line + "\n") to add the name where the line came from. I am still confused as to why this solution overwrites the previous additions to the txt file. When I have multiple files in the dr that start with 234567 I need them to be added into the txt file

Comment: if you want to append to a file, you need to do `with open(name, "a", newline='\n")...`. You'll notice the `"w"` (for write) is changed to `"a"` (for append)